# Obsolete library class

Tags: c#

What is the best way to prevent C# programmer from using particular library class?

Class is from external assembly so it is impossible to use `[Obsolete]` attribute on it. I tried to use Resharper custom patterns but it seems not to support generics types.

Comment: Remove it completely?

Comment: In library there are few other classes that are used in project. Library is third-party.

Comment: Oh, you don't have the code for the library?

Comment: That is an interesting question. What worked for us is asking him nicely not to use it :)

Comment: tell them you will beat them with a stick if they use it?

Comment: @user1019552, `In library there are few other classes that are used in project.` Could you clarify, are few classes or lot of classes? I believe that you may utilize Adapter pattern here if it's a critical issue

Comment: Class I would like to obsolete is ObservableCollection<T> because it causes memory leak. This class is so often use that some one may forget to use new version of it: MyObservableCollection<T>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patch the library method/class (there are several plugins for Reflector) - add `DeprecatedAttribute`, or modify its code to throw an exception, for example.

You can also make a special unit test which runs at CI server and fails if a particular deprecated item usage indicated.

Comment: I think you meant to say "Code Analysis" instead of unit test. Unit tests are for functionality, whereas code analysis is to enforce rules on the code itself. This is an instance where perhaps a custom code analysis rule could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can disassemble the library with ildasm, add `[Obsolete(true)]` attributes and reassemble with ilasm.

You might be able to find some assembly edit tool, like [Reflexil](http://reflexil.net/) together with a trial of Reflector.

Note that if you edit an assembly you loose all signing and stuff.